# Request: make spam flagging more descriptive (optional)

Tags: feature-request, spam, flagging

I've recently been on a bit of an anti-spam rampage on Super User. Have you posted a plug for a product you work on but haven't been clear about that relationship? *Flagged*! Are you linking to spammy sites with no real connection to the original question purely for promotional reasons? *Flagged*!

The problem is that for some answers I come across, at first glance it doesn't look like spam in an obvious way. I tend to come across answers like these during my lunch break so if I'm not busy I might dive deeper. At that point from searching Google, scanning the target site, looking across the user's profile etc - I will come to the realisation that the answer is spam and then flag it.

When flagging spam I can't provide any details:

[image: Flagging spam]

I end up having to use the "needs ♦ moderator attention" option and then writing any details under "other":

[image: Entering spam details]

**Could a field be added to the spam flag interface to provide details when they may be useful?**
Nine times out of ten I can flag as spam straight-up because it's obvious, but perhaps moderators would appreciate if some of the less obvious reports had a bit of detail attached? Or instead, should I just leave a comment on the original answer and then go ahead and flag as spam?

Yes, I hate spam that much!

Comment: Why not drop into Root Access or simply leave a comment for all to see?

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, I'm fine with leaving comments (as mentioned in the question at the end), and Root Access would work as well. Was just curious if anything *could* be added because it might be a quicker workflow overall.

Comment: curious, why blur out your flag count?

Comment: Ha, no real reason I guess @Sathya - I do live in Beijing though so maybe I just got used to the local self-censorship :)

Comment: /me proceeds to calculate flags based on flag weight

Comment: 36 total flags per day.

Comment: okay @Gareth :-)

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

[image: i dun liek descriptions]

Comment: Yes, that's perfect @Hello71 - exactly how I imagined! Thanks. I'd make the text entry optional as probably not every case would merit anything more than "this is spam".